# Error when removing last item from ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have a ListView with a onListItemListener, I have it so if you tap a ListView Item it removes it, but for some reason if I remove the last item form the list, the app crashes and gives me this error `(java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3)`

Does anyone have any idea what that means?

This is my code:

```
 @Override  
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {  
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
            adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(pos));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on? You shouldn't be getting it inside this function

Comment: @codeMagic 40, which is 'adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(pos));'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've figured it out, all the answers that said that the `pos` variable was one number too high seemed logical, but I tried them all and they didn't work.

It seems what was wrong was, when I would remove the last item from the list, it would try to refresh the ListView but there wouldn't be anything in it to refresh, so therefore the app would crash, I changed my code a little bit and it works great now! :) I dont fully understand why it works, but it does!

Thanks for all the answers guys!

```
@Override  
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {  
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);

        if (adapter.getCount() != adapter.getItemId(pos)) {
           adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(pos));
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
       }        
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I assumed you passed pos = 3 as parameter value. Because the size of list is 3, last element's position should be 2.

*EDIT:

Remember, start index of listview and adapter is different.
The ListView item pos starts from "1" as first position, adapter (such as array) starts from index "0" as first position.

```
adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(pos-1));
```

Comment: The size of the list is dynamic, You can add items to the list.

Comment: Actually, pos does start at 0, so if I try to do (pos-1), it gets screwed up when I remove the first item.  But I did find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) you should have been using id as the value to remove the item.

like this:

```
adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
If there are 4 items in lsitview then lat item would be at index 3 and first would be at index 0.

```
@Override  
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {  
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);
            adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(pos-1));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```